# how to get horizontally position of edittext by get line number?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

I want to get y position of edittext line with enter line number and it return y position of it
like as this:
`Int YpositionOfLineNumber = getYposition(int lineNumber);`
Can you help me?

Comment: You should show more of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `EditText` holds a `Layout` object that handles the text layout, and exposes all sorts of info about line size, spacing, offset, etc. This object has several methods to get coordinate information for lines in an `EditText`. Depending on exactly what you mean by "y position", there is the `Layout#getLineTop(int line)` method, or the `Layout#getLineBottom(int line)` method.

For example, to get the y-coordinate of the top of the 23rd line of an `EditText` named `edit`:

```
Layout layout = edit.getLayout();
int topLine = layout.getLineTop(22);
```

Please note that these methods measure with respect to the `Layout` object's area. If your `EditText` has `top` gravity, then the results should be accurate. If not, then the results will have to be adjusted by the vertical offset of the `Layout`.